# Apoc Dijkstra traversing in both directions while computing shortest path

Tags: neo4j, cypher, dijkstra, neo4j-apoc

I've been trying to use neo4j and its apoc process library to get shortest path between 2 nodes.

For example I create 2 nodes as below

```
CREATE (:Point {title:'A'})
CREATE (:Point {title:'B'})
```

Then I establish their relationship as such

```
MATCH (u1:Point {title:'A'}), (u2:Point {title: 'B'}) 
CREATE (u1)-[:distance {value:10}]->(u2)
```

Now I have established a directed relationship from A to B and not vice versa.
So when I call apoc Dijkstra as below

```
MATCH (start:Point {title: 'B'}), (end:Point {title: 'B'}) 
CALL apoc.algo.dijkstra(start, end, 'distance', 'value') YIELD path, weight 
RETURN path, weight
```

I am not supposed to get any result as their is no directed path from B to A. But I am getting the the same result as when I run the query using a path from A to B.

Can someone tell me why that is so? Why is Dijkstra disregarding the direction? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a `>` or `<` to the relationship type in your query.

```
MATCH (start:Point {title: 'B'}), (end:Point {title: 'B'}) 
CALL apoc.algo.dijkstra(start, end, 'distance>', 'value') YIELD path, weight 
RETURN path, weight
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know whether it was because I am inexperienced with Neo4j but I couldn't find any such detail in the apoc documentation.

Comment: What does the > or < mean in this?

Comment: It is the directon of the realtionship. The third parameter in the signature is `relationshipTypesAndDirections`.